# JRE 7 update 51 and the extension mechanism

Tags: java

I've developed an applet that uses Java extension mechanism to install an extension package. 
Both JARs are signed, and I have put this in the manifest:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

It works fine with the JRE 1.7 update 45, but with the last version of the JRE (1.7 update 51), I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyApplicationLibraryAllowableCodebase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.extension.ExtensionInstallationImpl.verifyJar(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.extension.ExtensionInstallationImpl.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.extension.ExtensionInstallationImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin.extension.ExtensionInstallationImpl.installExtension(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.ExtensionDependency.installExtension(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.ExtensionDependency.checkExtension(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.ExtensionDependency.checkExtensions(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.ExtensionDependency.checkExtensionsDependencies(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.parseExtensionsDependencies(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getClassPath(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I copy the package extension in the lib/ext directory of the JRE, then the applet works.
I've read [the changes in the new JRE](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/signed_code.xml), but how would I get this to work?

Comment: I tried with the latest version of java 7 (55), and I get the same error. I have set the security level to medium, and the URL is added to the list of exceptions to the JRE.

Comment: And the same with JRE 1.8.0_05.